# How to set cursor position in a Matplotlib TextBox widget?

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget

How do I force a cursor to appear at the end of the text in a [`TextBox`](https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html?highlight=textbox#matplotlib.widgets.TextBox) widget? I want to be able to create a `TextBox` widget, give it immediate focus and set the cursor to appear at the end of the text within it.

The following code...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

axbox = plt.axes([0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.075])

initial_text = "Change me"
text_box = TextBox(axbox, '', initial=initial_text)
text_box.position_cursor(len(initial_text)) # RuntimeError!

plt.show()
#text_box.position_cursor(len(initial_text))
```

...fails at the call to `position_cursor` with:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer
```

Is this because the figure needs to be drawn (rendered) before calling `position_cursor`?

If I comment out the failing line and uncomment the last line I don't get the runtime error but the cursor doesn't appear anywhere, let alone at the end of the text as I wanted.

Comment: `position_cursor` doesn't take an input of number of characters. It's the x position of the `Axes` instance that the `TextBox` resides in. See the source for what it does [here](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/widgets.html#TextBox.position_cursor). So even if this didn't give you a `RuntimeError`, using it with `len(initial_text)` is not the right way to use it...

Comment: That's a shame because using a number of characters would seem to me to be the more intuitive use case for a text entry widget. Anyhow, even `text_box.position_cursor(0)` doesn't result in the cursor appearing either.

Comment: Based on a quick look in the source, I think the function is used when the box is clicked on - it feeds the x-location of the click event to this function to move the cursor to where was clicked. So I don't know that it was really designed for the use you describe - hence not being the most "intuitive"

Comment: You're probably right. Maybe it should be called `_position_cursor()` instead in that case. Looking at the source I also tried the hack of `text_box.cursor_index = len(initial_text)` and then `text_box._rendercursor()` but that didn't make the cursor appear either.

Comment: Hmm, I just added an answer using that trick. It works for me in an interactive ipython figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to execute some code upon showing the figure you may use a single-shot timer. The callback of that timer may contain the code to give the `TextBox` focus and place the cursor accordingly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

axbox = plt.axes([0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.075])

initial_text = "Change me"
text_box = TextBox(axbox, '', initial=initial_text)

def autofocus():
    text_box.cursor_index = len(initial_text)
    text_box._rendercursor()
    text_box.begin_typing(None)


timer = plt.gcf().canvas.new_timer()
timer.single_shot = True
timer.add_callback(autofocus)
timer.start()

plt.show()
```

Running this, you may directly start typing once the figure opens.

Comment: That works - thanks! But, gosh, what a lot of work to do a simple task. I did try calling your `autofocus()` method directly without using a timer but I guess you need the timer to tell Matplotlib which canvas to use? Is that right?

Comment: No, the point is that you want to call `autofocus` at the moment the figure is created, i.e. once the event loop is started. If you call it beforehands, it will not make anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems the `position_cursor` function takes an `x` position in number of pixels from the left hand side of the figure. Not useful for your use case.

However, we can grab a couple of parts from that function and use them.

If I run in an ipython session, and make the figure interactive (`plt.ion()` after your module imports), and use

```
text_box.cursor_index = len(initial_text)
text_box._rendercursor()
```

it works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using ipython and if I try `plt.ion()` the app exits immediately. In my larger code-base from which this dummy example is taken I'm not using interactive mode.